# How to pass various derived classes of the same interface within a generic List as a parameter to the function?

Tags: c#, list, generics, interface, derived-class

How to pass a List with different inherited classes to the function takes the parent interface List?
The compiler generates an error.

```
    public interface ControlPoint
    {
    }

    public class Knot:  ControlPoint
    {
    }

    public class Node:  ControlPoint
    {
    }

    class Spline
    {
         List<Knot> knots=new List<Knot>();
         List<Node> nodes=new List<Node>();

         void Calculate(List<ControlPoint> points) {} //<------- Compiler Error

        void Test()
        {
           Calculate(knots);
           Calculate(nodes);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Does the compiler message, `Semicolon after method or accessor block is not valid`, not give you any idea what the problem is?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Two options:

1) If you're using C# 4 and .NET 4+, and you only need to iterate over the points in `Calculate`, just change the signature to:

```
    void Calculate(IEnumerable<ControlPoint> points)
```

This will use generic covariance.

2) You could make the method generic:

```
    void Calculate<T>(List<T> points) where T : ControlPoint
```

I would prefer the first in general - and even if you're *not* using .NET 4 / C# 4, if you can change `Calculate` to use `IEnumerable<T>` instead of `List<T>`, that would be cleaner - so you could mix the two and have a generic method taking `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: Thank you so much. The second is very suitable